# connectionString encryption

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

I'm trying to encrypt the connection strings in my web.config. I'm following the instructions from [Walkthrough: Creating and Exporting an RSA Key Container](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2w117ede.aspx). However, when I get to the part with the command:

```
aspnet_regiis -pe "connectionStrings" -app "/MyApplication" -prov "MyProvider"
```

it keeps complaining:

```
"The configuration for the virtual path '/MyApplication' and site 'Default Web Site' cannot be opened

Failed to map the path '/myapplication'
Failed!
```

I'm fairly sure I've followed the instructions correctly. I created the project named 'MyApplication' directly in the 'C:' root.

Any ideas? Perhaps I should be following a different set of instructions?

Answer (score 11):

Thanks for your answers. Turned out I needed to run the command prompt as "Administrator"

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the MyApplication folder as a virtual directory in IIS under the default web site?  That seems to be what it's looking for, not a folder path...

According [to this MSDN post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), you can use `-site` to define the site to target.  An excerpt from that site:

> Use the –app option to identify the application for which the
>   Web.config file will be encrypted and the -site option to identify
>   which Web site the application is a part of. The Web site is
>   identified using the site number from the Internet Information
>   Services (IIS) metabase. You can retrieve the site number from the
>   INSTANCE_META_PATH server variable in the ServerVariables collection.
>   For example, when IIS is installed, a Web site named "Default Web
>   Site" is created as site 1. In pages served from that site, the
>   INSTANCE_META_PATH server variable returns "/LM/W3SVC/1". If you do
>   not specify a -site option, site 1 is used.

Comment: But what if it is not in the default web site. How do I define it?

Answer (score 0):

/MyApplication is a virtual path and the message seems to indicate that path is not available i.e. there is no http://localhost/MyApplication. Did you forget to create virtual directory for your app in IIS?